# Recorrer Array dentro de un Array, para despues sacar el promedio php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo el Siguiente array

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "value" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "value" => 1
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "value" => 1
  ]
]
```

Para poder realizar el promedio segun mi logica tengo que recorrer el array y sacar cada uno de los elementos, es correcto?

en este caso intente con for y foreach pero al parecer estoy haciendo algo mal

Comment: Para hacer un promedio simple tendrías que sumar los valores y dividirlos por la cantidad de valores sumados. Puedes hacerlo recorriendo el array y/o usando funciones de php, yo lo pasaría a una colección y usaría el método `avg()`

Comment: por defecto me los da en una coleccion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener el promedio del ejemplo que muestras no necesitas recorrer el array, puedes utilizar funciones propias de php.

Por ejemplo:

```
$array = [
    ['value' => 1],
    ['value' => 2],
    ['value' => 3],
];

$promedio = array_sum(array_column($array, 'value')) / count($array); // 2
```

Documentación:

- array_column: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-column.php
- count: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.count
- array_sum: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-sum.php

---

En Laravel si tienes una colección puedes utilizar el método avg:

Ejemplo:

```
$promedio = $coleccion->avg('value');
```

Documentación:

- avg: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-avg